# Loading a Magento mail template and fill its vars from code?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, email-templates

I am loading my mail template like this:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$myTemplate = $mailTemplate->load($templateId);
```

Now I can get the template content using:

```
$text = $myTemplate ->getData('template_text');
```

This works, but *$text* still contains the placeholders for the variables, like {{var myvar}} or {{store url=""}}. Is there a way to fill those placeholders when loading the template without sending the mail? I want to show the text to the user, but with filled placeholders.

Possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` has a method `getProcessedTemplate()`. You only need to pass along the proper variables for your placeholders.

For example, if your template contains placeholders like this:

```
{{var firstname}} {{var lastname}}
```

you can use:

```
$sTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->load($templateId)
    ->getProcessedTemplate(array(
        'firstname' => 'John',
        'lastname' => 'Doe'
    ));
```

to get your placeholders resolved.

Answer (score 2):

To load an email template and fill it with variables you can do the following:

```
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                            ->loadDefault('<your_email_template>');  

    //create template variables        
    $emailTemplateVariables                 = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['firstname']    = <firstname_var>;
    $emailTemplateVariables['lastname']     = <lastname_var>;
    // in your tample tou can use {var firstname} and {var lastname}

    //fill template variables in email template
    $processedTemplate              = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName('<name>');
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('<emailaddress>');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($this->__('<your subject>'));

    //send mail
    $emailTemplate->send(<receiver_emailaddress>, <receiver_name>, $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Hopefully someone could use it ;-)

Kind regards,

Martijn