# Email templates in magento

Tags: php, magento, email, templates

I am working on custom extension.I am facing two issues.

1 ) I created a  custom html page in `Locale->en_Us->template->email->testEmail.hmtl`.
And this is my config,.xml code :

```
   <template>    <email>
    <mymodule_email_settings_client_email_template>
                    <label>Follow up Emails</label>
                    <file>test_email.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </mymodule_email_settings_client_email_template>
                </email>
            </template>
```

when i try to load it in my controller it reutrns me empty .this is my code of accessing template.

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('mymodule_email_settings_client_email_template');
```

2) I want to load transactional and newsletter templates by there ids.I have id but don't know how can i use that templates on my custom emails.I want only the code to access the templates like above nothing more than that.Can i use that templates in my custom emails ? Thanks

Comment: hi plz check path for email template in system.xml

Comment: @magExp thank but I didn't use it in system.xml ? where did you see system.xml

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017951/loading-a-magento-mail-template-and-fill-its-vars-from-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check following links use to define custom email template

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-sending-custom-emails

http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

hope this help you

Comment: What about the second part of the question ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017951/loading-a-magento-mail-template-and-fill-its-vars-from-code

Comment: How you would differentiate between transactional and Newsletter Email Templates ?

Comment: I user above reference answer and it loads the transactional emails by there id.